# Unit Test fails in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xcode8

I get this error message every time I run my unit tests in Xcode 8

```
Validation for xctestrun file failed:
(
    "For these test runs, UITargetAppPath should be provided"
)
```

Comment: Does your build Scheme contain a UI Test Project?

Comment: Unselect and select `Host Application` in test target works for me

Answer (score 175):

Go to each of your test targets (e.g. MyProjectTests and MyProjectUITests) in the project settings and select "None" for the "Target Application" dropdown.
Then reselect your Target Application back for the same targets. 
This should reset the test targets and make XCode less confused.

Comment: This worked for me - I had to do it for both my Core and UI test modules.

Comment: In Xcode 9.2: Open project, click project name (top left), select test target in dropdown (also top left of new view), change "Target Application" to "None", then back to what it was before.

Comment: This has the effect of updating TEST_TARGET_NAME in the pbxproj to the current app name. Sometimes Xcode doesn’t rename this setting when you change the application name.

Comment: In Xcode 10: General -> Testing -> Host Application dropdown.

Answer (score -11):

close your Xcode and open it again it's working with me

Comment: I'm sure we would have tried closing and opening before posting for help. This is not a solution man.

Comment: ok try to reassign the Unit test target project.

from project Tab

Comment: switched target application to none, then back to my app and it helped. Issue appeared after project/scheme/workspace renaming. So visually nothing changed, but yes...reassign helped